# Who are the largest customers of the Vanguard group?

Tags: corporate-finance

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vanguard_Group), Vanguard is owned by its customers. Is there a list available of the largest customers of the Vanguard group?